# Login with Facebook in app in titanium

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, titanium-mobile, appcelerator

I want facebook account to to be treated as authentication for my mobile titanium application.
I am using this code 
facebook login

```
 Ti.Facebook=Titanium.Facebook = require('facebook');
 Ti.Facebook.appid = FACEBOOK_APP_ID;
 Ti.Facebook.permissions = ['publish_stream']; // Permissions your app needs
 Ti.Facebook.forceDialogAuth = true;
 var btnLogin = Titanium.UI.createButton({
   title: 'Hello',
   top: 10,
   width: 100,
   height: 50
});
win.add(btnLogin);
btnLogin.addEventListener('click',function(e)
{ 
Ti.Facebook.addEventListener('login', function(e) {
    if (e.success) {
        alert('Logged In');
    } else if (e.error) {
        alert(e.error);
    } else if (e.cancelled) {
        alert("Canceled");
    }
});
Ti.Facebook.authorize();
});
```

and FB logout

```
    var btnLogout = Titanium.UI.createButton({
       title: 'Hello',
       top: 10,
       width: 100,
       height: 50
    });
    win2.add(btnLogout);
    btnLogout.addEventListener('click',function(e)
    {
     Ti.Facebook.addEventListener('logout', function(e) {
        alert('Logged out');
    });
    Ti.Facebook.logout();
});
```

But this is giving a dialogue to enter email and password.There are certain apps that are using facebook account as their sigup and do not open that dialogue and directly gets login.
I found another resource 
    https://gist.github.com/damienb/855583
but I am not sure how to use it.Please give me guidance who to implement this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Titanium.Facebook is deprecated now.
http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.Facebook

Use Modules.Facebook.
http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Modules.Facebook

Sample Example given in the doc is -

```
var fb = require('facebook');
fb.appid = FACEBOOK_APP_ID;
fb.permissions = ['publish_stream']; // Permissions your app needs
fb.forceDialogAuth = true;
fb.addEventListener('login', function(e) {
if (e.success) {
    alert('Logged In');
} else if (e.error) {
    alert(e.error);
} else if (e.cancelled) {
    alert("Canceled");
}
});
fb.authorize();
```

In your code, add facebook login & logout listener out of the click listener of your buttons(btnLogin and btnLogout). Because every time you click on your button the event listener is added that many times.

If you want the SSO property to work.
Set
`fb.forceDialogAuth = false;`
If the official facebook app is installed it will verify from that without opening the dialog and if the device doesn't have the facebook app it will open safari and asks for email/password if the user is not logged in.